# looking for a working linux command line tool to download from rapidshare

Tags: python, linux, command-line, download

I'm wondering if anyone knows about a working command line tool for linux to download using premium account on rapidshare. I've seen a [python solution](http://juanjoalvarez.net/rapidsucker), which does not work for me -- returns urllib2 error message

```
urlopen error unknown url type: https
```

and my knowledge of python is not yet deep enough to figure out why: might be a recent RS change or something is wrong with my settings.

Any other tools around someone may be using and could share a link?

Answer (score 5):

[`wget`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/) works well. You have to point it to a file containing the cookie corresponding to your Rapidshare account (e.g. the `cookies.txt` in Firefox's profile directory).

```
wget --load-cookies /path/to/cookies.txt http://...
```

Answer (score 4):

[`curl`](http://curl.haxx.se/) is a remarkably powerful command-line tool for squeezing things out of web servers.  I can't say about RapidShare in particular, but if you see what the manual download is doing, you can get curl to post the same forms, for example.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Plowshare](http://code.google.com/p/plowshare/).
It let's you (depending on file hosting)

- download
- upload
- list
- delete

Answer (score 2):

Here's a tutorial for a command line tool to download from rapidshare:
http://fedoracoreproject.blogspot.com/2009/03/linux-command-line-tool-to-download.html

Answer (score 0):

To get urllib2 to open https URLs you need Python with SSL support. How to get it depends on your distribution.

Comment: The one I have problems with is Suse 9.3 with Python 2.6.

I found an <a href="http://www.heikkitoivonen.net/blog/2008/10/14/ssl-in-python-26/">article about Python 2.6 with SSL</a>, but it looks like I'll need to modify the script I linked in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Nice commandline tool for RapidShare and many other services (MegaUploads, HotFiles etc). It allows simultanous transfer from different services:

http://svn.pld-linux.org/cgi-bin/viewsvn/toys/rsget.pl/

Just create file with list of URLs (# for comment), and start rsget.pl list-of-urls
It monitors file with url list, so you can add/remove links without restarting script (i.e. breaking current transfer).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using Ruby (it's pretty similar to Python anyway), check out the [rapidshare gem](https://github.com/defkode/rapidshare) (which I contribute to, BTW).

Installation: `gem install rapidshare`

Example of simple use:

```
require 'rapidshare'

files_to_download = %w{
  https://rapidshare.com/files/829628035/HornyRhinos.jpg
  https://rapidshare.com/files/3103991314/HappyHippos.jpg
  https://rapidshare.com/files/3882189288/ElegantElephants.jpg
}

rs = Rapidshare::API.new(:login => 'my_login', :password => 'my_password')

files_to_download.each do |file|
  rs.download(file) || puts "ERROR downloading #{file}"    
end
```

There is a more advanced [downloading client](https://github.com/defkode/rapidshare/blob/master/examples/rsclient.rb) available in /examples directory.